# Big O notation - recursion

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Found this algorithm online, I can't work out how to do the maths to find its complexity. I do understand its worst case is 2^n

```
// A simple recursive function to check whether C is an interleaving of A and B
bool isInterleaved(char *A, char *B, char *C)
{
    // Base Case: If all strings are empty
    if (!(*A || *B || *C))
        return true;

    // If C is empty and any of the two strings is not empty
    if (*C == '\0')
        return false;

    // If any of the above mentioned two possibilities is true,
    // then return true, otherwise false
    return ( (*C == *A) && isInterleaved(A+1, B, C+1))
           || ((*C == *B) && isInterleaved(A, B+1, C+1));
}
```

Comment: @PaulS. But there is a `OR` between two statements, means either first statement is going to be true or another

Comment: what do you mean?? @PaulS.

Comment: @psyco oh yeah, I was thinking in an `if..else` mentality, that `OR` does make it `2^n`, you're right

Comment: I understand its 2^n but I don't understand how to do them math @PaulS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it) , `There is no mechanical procedure that can be used to get the BigOh.`

Comment: @PaulS. But you make assumptions for given algorithms, you can calculate the BigOh, but each algorithm is different.  This is not a duplicate.

Comment: I have read through that article multiple times @PaulS.helps me without a doubt for all other algorithms apart from this one

Comment: @PaulS. I believe the complexity of this solution is O(n+m), if len(A)=n and len(B)=m as len(C)=n+m. I've written an ans justifying this, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the complexity as a function of the number `n` of characters in `C`. Let's call that `f(n)`.

The first `if` blocks are just doing simple checks no matter what, so we can ignore them for now (constant complexity).

The meat of the algorithm is of course these lines:

`((*C == *A) && isInterleaved(A+1, B, C+1))
    || ((*C == *B) && isInterleaved(A, B+1, C+1));`

Checks `(*C == ...)` are again constant time complexity. Now, `isInterleaved(..., ..., C+1)` is calling the algorithm with a `C` shorter by 1: it's complexity is therefore `f(n-1)`.

We can then put it all together as:

`f(n) = 
  k1 +
  (k2 + f(n-1)) +
  (k3 + f(n-1))`

With `k1`, `k2` and `k3` being some constants. Reorder the terms, we get:

`f(n) = 2 * f(n-1) + k`

Where `k` is, again, some constant. Now, expanding the recursion, we get:

`f(n) = 2 * (2 * ( 2 * (... f(0) + k0) + k1) + k2) + ... + k_n)
      = 2 * (2 * (2 * (... 2*(2*(f(0) + k0) + k1) + k2) + ... + k_n)
      = 2 * (2 * (2 * (... 2*(2^2*(f(0) + k0) + 2*k1) + k2) + ... + k_n)
      = 2 * (2 * (2 * (... 2*(2^3*(f(0) + k0) + 2^2*k1 + 2*k2) + ... + k_n)
 f(n) = 2^n * (f(0) + k0) + 2^(n-1) * k1 + 2^(n-2) * k2 + ...`

Dividing that all by `2^n`, we get:

`f(n) / 2^n = (f(0) + k0) + k1 / 2 + k2 / 4 + ... + k_n / 2^n`

All of these terms are bounded: It is a property of the sum of `2^{-n}` that it will approach 2 without ever reaching it, no matter how many terms you sum. Now, since all your `k` constants are just simple checks, it makes sense that they are also all bounded. Therefore, we know that there exist some constant `K` such that `k0 < K, k1 < K, ..., k_n < K`. Your `f(n)/2^n` then becomes:

`f(n) / 2^n < f(0) + K * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/2^n)`

Now, the first two checks ensure that `f(0)` is constant as well, so you have proven that the complexity of that function divided by 2^n is indeed bounded, which is sufficient to say that `f(n) is O(2^n)`.

You can skim over most of these 'there exists a constant such that...'; the main observation to make is (using the 'handwavily equivalent-ish' symbol `~`):

`f(n) ~ f(n-1) + f(n-1)
f(n) ~ 2 * f(n-1)
f(n) ~ O(2^n)`

I have also slightly cheated by starting from the assumption that the length of `C` is the only parameter that matters for computing the complexity, but how you can rigorously show that the complexity is equivalent for various lengths of `A` and `B` is left as an exercise to the reader !

Comment: how would you compute it considering a and b matter for calculating the complexity?

Comment: @user3667111: rigorously, you would write your complexity `f(n_a, n_b, n_c)` and end up with `f(n_a, n_b, n_c) ~ f(n_a-1, n_b, n_c-1) + f(n_a, n_b-1, n_c-1)`, with limit conditions of `f(0, ., .) = k_a`, `f(., 0, .) = k_b` and `f(., ., 0) = k_c` (ignoring the laundry-eating which might occur if either `A` or `B` is empty but not `C`), and proceed similarly. More intuitively (and hand-waveily), we will only consider the first `n_a` and `n_b` characters of `A` and `B` respectively, such that `n_a + n_b = n`, so `n` is really the only important parameter.

Comment: I should say, the above holds true only for the computation of the worst-case complexity. If you need to compute average or best-case complexity, doing the rigorous derivation might actually very well be required.

Comment: I don't understand the expanding the recursion bit? you suddenly jumped to f(n) = 2 * (2 * ( 2 * (... f(0) + k0) + k1) + k2 + ... + k_n)
     = 2^n * (f(0) + k0) + 2^(n-1) * k1 + 2^(n-2) * k2 + ...

Comment: You simply distribute the terms `2*(a + b) => (2*a + 2*b)`, `2*(2*(a + b) + c) => 2*2*(a+b) + 2*c` etc... starting from the center. Edited the post to make that a bit clearer

Comment: Ah okay, do you know what values would have to be entered to get a worst-case scenario?

Comment: Passing in matching strings which differ in size should try all combinations until it has exhausted `C` every time. Doing it with `A=B=C='aaaa...aaaa'` `n` times results in `2 * 2^n - 1` calls, which is `O(2^n)`

Answer (score 1):

See if you can reduce the problem by splitting the `return` into more lines,

```
// A simple recursive function to check whether C is an interleaving of A and B
bool isInterleaved(char *A, char *B, char *C)
{
    // Base Case: If all strings are empty
    if (!(*A || *B || *C))
        return true;

    // If C is empty and any of the two strings is not empty
    if (*C == '\0')
        return false;

    // If any of the above mentioned two possibilities is true,
    // then return true, otherwise false
    if ((*C == *A) && isInterleaved(A+1, B, C+1))
        return true;
    return (*C == *B) && isInterleaved(A, B+1, C+1);
}
```

"Factor out" `B` to produce two methods

```
bool isInterleavedA(char *A, char *C)
{
    // Base Case: If all strings are empty
    if (!(*A || *C))
        return true;

    // If C is empty and any of the two strings is not empty
    if (*C == '\0')
        return false;

    // If any of the above mentioned two possibilities is true,
    // then return true, otherwise false
    return (*C == *A) && isInterleavedA(A+1, C+1);
}

bool isInterleavedB(char *A, char *B, char *C)
{
    bool result = isInterleavedA(A, C);
    if (!(*B) && result)
        return true;
    return (*C == *B) && isInterleavedB(A, B+1, C+1);
}
```

Now we can see `isInterleavedA` is `O(n)` and the BigOh `isInterleavedB` will be the same as `isInterleaved`, which will be.. `N + MN`?

Comment: I'm not confident at this, please edit if you see mistakes!

Comment: So enter values such as a=xxxx and b = xxxx and c = xxxxxxxy That is definitely not a complexity of O(n+m)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following case.

```
A = "ab"
B = "aa"
C = "aa"
```

now the recursion will be executed as below,

```
fn(ab, aa, aa)
=> fn(b, aa, a) + fn(ab, a, a)
=> false + fn(b, a, null) + fn(b, null, a) + fn(ab, null, null)
```

number of function call is 6.

Now if you add a single a at the first for all of them, like

```
A = "aab"
B = "aaa"
C = "aaa"
```

you will see this time number of function call will be 14.

add similarly one a more. then it will be 30..
then 62 then ...
you can see its simply `2^n - 2`. or like so.

So the actual complexity here is `2^n` not n^2.

This is happening because you are not using memorization here.

Comment: Your case is not a valid input case. len(C)=len(A)+len(B)

Comment: This problem can be solved by much easier and less costly way, but I think you are interested in the complexity calculation here. So, you can still make the same code O(n^2) by just adding memorization. This approach is known as dynamic programming. So if you are interested I can help you on that.

Comment: Are there any constraints stated here, like this?

Comment: @Md.SumsuddinShojib How did you get to the solution 2^n-2?

Comment: just add a count++ on the top of the function and you will see that the series is like 6, 14, 30, 62, 126 .... which is 2^n-2. or see carefully my case(which is worst case) and add one 'a' each time. you will see that it simply double the root function calls. I need time to visualize the senario.